# MVC call controller from radio button onclick

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I call an action in my controller and pass a parameter from a radio button onclick event?  I'm new to MVC....

I have this code which will call a javascript function, but I wanted to see if I can call an action and pass a parameter instead of calling a javascript function

```
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SiteAddressModel.SiteId, item.SiteId, new { @onclick = "radiobuttontest();"})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is on of the differences between asp.net MVC and webforms in both cases you are using javascript to make a post or ajax call the difference is in webforms it's hidden by the framework. MVC give you greater control but it requires you do the work, if you have the javascript working your done.

Comment: ok, thanks.  I have that working, I was just trying to see if there was an easier or more direct way of doing it.